# open-in not tab not showing in safari for .mp3

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have associated .mp3 with my app by adding the following in my info.plist

[image]

After installing my app in the device. I tried to browse a .mp3 in safari. But safari is not showing the open-in button.

Why is that so?. Is it not allowed?. Am I missing something here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything there, thats about safari does not allow mp3 to be opened by 3rd party apps. Similarly, it will not allow image type files as well.

[image: mp3 uti setup for xcode]

For mp3 files here is the correct document type uti setup

The document types interface is available in the Targets -> [YOURPROJECTNAME] -> info tab.

its possible to test by simply sending the mp3 file to yourself and launching open in menu for the mp3 file.

Comment: Thanks. my setting does work .But I was trying with safari alone.